# If $p$ is a prime which can be expressed as $a^4 + b^2$, then prove that $p^p$ can also be expressed as $m^4+ n^2$

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ is a prime which can be expressed as $a^4 + b^2$, then prove that $p^p$ can also be expressed as $m^4+ n^2$.

I tried solving this question by splitting $m^4 + n^2$ into 2 factors'

$$(m^2+n+m\sqrt{2n})(m^2 -n + m\sqrt{2n})$$

and simultaneously splitting p^p as $(p^t)p^{p-t}$ and then trying to prove that there is a integer solution, but it is really difficult to prove that there exists integer solutions using this method. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Take $m= a p^k$ and $n= b p^{2k}$ for some unknown $k$ (just for now)

We want to prove that $m^4 +n^2 = p^p$ if we are given that $a^4+b^2=p$

substitute instead of $m$ and $n$ there values we get :

$ (a p^k)^4+ (b p^{2k})^2 = p^p$

expanding brackets and by power rules and some simple arithmetic we arrive at

$ a^4 *p^{4k} + b^2 * p^{4k} = p^p$

which is $ p^{4k} (a^4+b^2) = p^p$ and because its known that $a^4 +b^2 =p$ we substitute it  in the equation and arrive at :

$ p^{4k}*p = p^p$ which is $p^{4k+1}= p^p$ because this equation have the same base $p$ we need to solve it for the powers which means that :

$4 k+1 = p$ and solving for $k$ the unknown we get $k = \frac{p-1}{4}$ and because the prime that are re-presentable in the form $a^4+b^2=p$ have to be $p=1 \mod 4$ then we are guaranteed that $k$ is an integer namely $\frac{p-1}{4}$.

to conclude if $a^4 +b^2=p$ is a valid solution for $p$ using $a,b$ then :

$(a*p^{\frac{p-1}{4}})^4+(b*p^{\frac{p-1}{2}})^2 =p^p$